# PHP Webservice mySQL query - General explaination

Tags: php, web-services

Wanting to get some clarity for the below code, I have made comments next to each line and question marks where I am need some assistance please

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';                    // Select all data

$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);         // Connects to server and executes select all query
$query -> execute(array(':email' => $email));    // ????
$data = $query -> fetchObject();                 // Stores the results on the executed query in $data??
```

Comment: The bind above is pointless....? You haven't named the parameter in your query at all. The `:email` you see is what's called a placeholder. You use that to bind to within a query. If you were to use it, you'd have to modify your `$sql` to look like : `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email`

Comment: you can get rid of `$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);` and `$query -> execute(array(':email' => $email))` entirely if you're not going to use placeholders and simply do `$query = $this -> conn -> query($sql);` otherwise, RTM http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$email substitutes your ':email' with $email variable.

[See examples here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

In your case,  since you don't have any parameter marker, you can directly execute the query without any parameter binding.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';                   
$query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);         
$query -> execute();   
$data = $query -> fetchObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

execute is fetching the sql.

`:email => $email` this is binding email to `$email` variable.

btw, u got no email param, why u need bindparam?? u need to bind when u write some sql like

```
SELECT * FROM users where email = :email
```

Answer (score 1):

The ':email' => $email portion is binding whatever $email is to the :email param in the sql statement. As your SQL statement doesn't have an :email portion, this isn't doing anything.

This example shows how it could possibly be used:

```
$email = 'myEmail@aol.com';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users where email = :email'; 

$query = $this->conn->prepare($sql);         
$query->execute(array(':email' => $email));    
$data = $query->fetchObject();
```